# HTTP DELETE request comes in as GET

Tags: php, codeigniter, rest, http, postman

I have a Codeigniter 3 API system that is based on [chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver](https://github.com/chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver).

Now, everything was working OK, but for some reason the system stopped detecting `DELETE` request types.
Whenever I send a `DELETE` request it is identified as a `GET` request.

I am sending my requests via [Postman for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en)

Has anyone come across this issue before?

EDIT:

My controller lookst like so:

```
class MyClass extends REST_Controller{
   public function test_GET(){ /* This is called when I access the API with a GET request*/}
   public function test_DELETE(){ /* Similarly, this will be called upon DELETE request*/ }
}
```

My url for the first method would be

```
http://localhost/api/MyClass/test?API-KEY=XXXXXXXXXX&x=y
```

The `REST_Controller` identifies this here:

[`$controller_method = $object_called.'_'.$this->request->method;`](https://github.com/chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver/blob/e25895c5dff35df08cde8b040e25b04b9fd05a0d/application/libraries/REST_Controller.php#L362)

Comment: I had a similar problem and for quick solution I used post and created new hidden field with the name _method and value DELETE. But if you want to check further you may find your answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/165779/are-the-put-delete-head-etc-methods-available-in-most-web-browsers

Comment: What http server are you using?